# Google Spreadsheet GeoChart with labels rather than numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

I am trying to create a mapchart that would display words used in different countries upon hovering them. I want to embed it into Google Sites, so I do not have much liberty at playing with its code, so I need to use Google Spreadsheets. It appears this chart is mostly used for displaying numerical data, but I can see it can display labels too:
[image: it displays Italy's label when hovered]
However, no color is applied if the value is not a number, while as I will only have data for 20-something countries, I would like these to be a different color. Do you have any idea how to bypass this problem, or do you have any alternate solutions to my conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have arrived at a sollution, not at all flawless, but close enough to the goal I wished to achieve.

I have created a following dataset for a Geo Marker Chart:
[image: data input]

region | concatenated region + ": " + label I wanted to display | size, whatever number (just add a bigger number with no country assigned to make the dots smaller

I ended up with this
[image: final result]